# How can i destroy a session from a user in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sorcery

I use sorcery for registration and also use doorkeeper. I want to destroy session after 30 minutes when user is inactive. I tried like this but it doesn't work.

First add this submodule to sorcery:

## config/initializers/sorcery.rb

```
Rails.application.config.sorcery.submodules = [:session_timeout]
```

Session timeout is configurable like this:

## config/initializers/sorcery.rb

```
Rails.application.config.sorcery.configure do |config|
  config.session_timeout = 3600 # This is in seconds. You could also write 1.hour
  config.session_timeout_from_last_action = true # session timeout is calculated from the last valid activity. By default this is false.
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try

Like this way in controller

```
before_filter :session_expires
before_filter :update_sessions

def session_expires
  @time_left = (session[:expires_at] - Time.now).to_i
  unless @time_left > 0
    reset_session #clear sessions
    redirect_to '/'
  end
end

def update_sessions
  session[:expires_at] = 30.minutes.from_now
end
```

Comment: I can't login. It forced me to logout.